# Micro integrator hostname problem in cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, wso2

When running WSO2 Micro-integrator inside a docker container as a task in AWS, I get an error in the logs about the hostname? In the Dockerfile I don't specifically set the hostname of the container in any way. I created the task using the Cloudformation tool and do not get this error when running the container locally. I tried running on a different VPC as well, without any result. The error remains.

FYI: It is supposed to accept traffic on port 8290 and allow it to send outbound to any IP in the world.  Currently I have both inbound and outbound rules set to allow on 0.0.0.0/0 with all protocols.

The full error is as follows:

> at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
>   at
>   org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:88)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)

In case anyone is wondering:
I have setup a new VPC, complete with internet gateway, routes and route tables. The instance will run but I am unable to connect to it in any way.

The following script is run to get the task and make it available:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "myVPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/16",
                "Tags": [
                    {"Key":"Name", "Value":"myVPC"
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
        "myInternetGateway" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
              "Properties" : {
              }
           },
        "myRouteTable": {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
          "Properties" : {
              "VpcId" : {
                    "Ref": "myVPC"
              }
            }
        },
        "mySubPublic": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1a",
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/28",
                "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "myVPC"
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": "myInternetGateway"
        },
        "mySubnetRoutetable": {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
          "Properties" : {
              "RouteTableId" : {
                    "Ref": "myRouteTable"
                },
              "SubnetId" : {
                    "Ref": "mySubPublic"
                }
            }
        },
        "myVPCGatewayAttachment": {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
          "Properties" : {
              "InternetGatewayId" : {
                    "Ref": "myInternetGateway"
                },
              "VpcId" : {
                    "Ref": "myVPC"
                }
            }
        },
        "myRoute": {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Route",
          "Properties" : {
              "GatewayId" : {
                    "Ref": "myInternetGateway"
                },
            "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
              "RouteTableId" : {
                    "Ref": "myRouteTable"
                }
            }
        },
        "mySecGroup": {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties" : {
              "GroupDescription" : "my security group for all incoming and outgoing.",
              "GroupName" : "mySecGroup",
              "SecurityGroupEgress" : [ {
                  "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
                  "Description" : "Allow machine to reach internet.",
                  "FromPort" : -1,
                  "IpProtocol" : -1,
                  "ToPort" : -1
                } ],
              "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                  "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
                  "Description" : "Allow machine to be reached from the entire internet.",
                  "FromPort" : -1,
                  "IpProtocol" : -1,
                  "ToPort" : -1
                } ],
              "VpcId" : {"Ref": "myVPC"}
            },
            "DependsOn": "myVPC"
        },
        "myCluster": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
            "Properties": {
                "ClusterName": "myCluster"
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "myVPC"
            ]
        },
        "myLogs": {
          "Type" : "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
          "Properties" : {
              "LogGroupName" : "myLogGroup",
              "RetentionInDays" : 7
            }
        },
        "myDockerTask": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "Properties": {
                "ContainerDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "Cpu": 1024,
                        "Image": "<NRHERE>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my",
                        "Memory": 2048,
                        "MemoryReservation": 2048,
                        "Name": "myESBContainer",
                        "LogConfiguration": {
                            "LogDriver": "awslogs",
                            "Options": {
                                "awslogs-group": {"Ref": "myLogs"},
                                "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Cpu": "1024",
                "ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<NRHERE>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
                "Family": "myESB",
                "Memory": "2048",
                "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
                "RequiresCompatibilities": [
                    "FARGATE",
                    "EC2"
                ],
                "TaskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<NRHERE>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
            },
        },
        "myService": {
          "Type" : "AWS::ECS::Service",
          "Properties" : {
              "Cluster" : {"Fn::GetAtt": ["myCluster", "Arn"]},
              "DesiredCount" : 1,
              "DeploymentController": {"Type": "ECS"},

              "LaunchType" : "FARGATE",
              "NetworkConfiguration" : {
                 "AwsvpcConfiguration" : {
                      "AssignPublicIp" : "ENABLED",
                      "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Fn::GetAtt": ["mySecGroup", "GroupId"]} ],
                      "Subnets" : [ {"Ref": "mySubPublic"}]
                    }
              },
              "SchedulingStrategy" : "REPLICA",
              "ServiceName" : "myService",
              "TaskDefinition": {"Ref": "myDockerTask"}
            },
            "DependsOn": "mySubPublic"
        },
        "myDeadLetterQueue": {
          "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue",
          "Properties" : {
              "QueueName" : "myDeadLetterQueue"
            }
        },
        "myQueue": {
          "Type" : "AWS::SQS::Queue",
          "Properties" : {
              "QueueName" : "myQueue",
              "RedrivePolicy": {
                  "deadLetterTargetArn" : {"Fn::GetAtt": ["myDeadLetterQueue", "Arn"]},
                  "maxReceiveCount" : 2
              }
            },
          "DependsOn": "myDeadLetterQueue"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You are unable to connect (ssh?) to the container instance running your ecs task?

Comment: No, I run a service inside the container exposed to port 8290. When I start the task (Fargate by the way), the container starts with the error mentioned above. The state is "running" when I look at it but I'm not able to connect using port 8290. When I run the same container locally, I have no problem connecting.
As per your suggestion in my last topic (about cloudformation) I created the routetables and internet gateway and attached these to the VPC. I will post the entire JSON file in my topic to clarify a bit more. I got the feeling it has something to do with routing.

Comment: Fargate uses ` awsvpc` network mode. Have you enabled public ip for them? Also are your fargate tasks running in a public subnet? Finally, security groups for the tasks have been double checked to be open?

Comment: I will upload the entire cloudformation script use but I'm pretty sure the questions are all marked with yes.

Comment: Had a quick look. I can't see any [PortMappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html) in your task definition?

Comment: Correct observation. I removed those to ensure there were no errors in that respect. I wasn't sure wheter any of the mappings could interfere with hostname error, therefore I removed them. [EDIT]: To be clear, I'm trying to make my config as "open" as I can. I can always close it down later. Therefore I have the traffic outbound and inbound set to everything.

Comment: They should be added. Otherwise containers will not have any exposed ports to the host instance. Can check with that, how it goes.

Comment: I will absolutely add them again, but I doubt this will remove the hostname error? The task is set to initially only accept incoming traffic. Hostname errors on the docker instance don't have anything to do with incoming calls right? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I tried adding the portmapping again but the error remains.

Comment: I found the problem and got it fixed now! Thanks @Marcin for your assist once more.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Also, wanted to ask if Port mapping was also needed or it works without the mapping?

Comment: Haven't tried without port mapping just yet, but since the previous version did work without I assume you could skip it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately found the problem. The software could not identify itself because it used localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 for local loopback.
Since I am not in control of the software I tried adding the following to the VPC:

```
"EnableDnsSupport": true,
"EnableDnsHostnames": true,
```

This worked and the task is now able to resolve it's own hostname, no longer crashing.